# No matching function error C++ constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I got the following error message when calling the constructor of the class VS1838B

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘IRrecv::IRrecv()’
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinoReceptorIR){
                                    ^
```

This is part of the header for the VS1838B class:

```
#ifndef INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H
#define INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#include "IRremoteInt.h"

class VS1838B{

public:
    //Constructor
    VS1838B(int pinIR);

    //Atributes
    int _pinInput;
    IRrecv _receptorIR;                   
    decode_results _buffer;  

};

#endif  /* INFRAREDRECEIVERVS1838B_H */
```

And this is part of the cpp for the same class:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "InfraRedReceiverVs1838b.h"
#include "IRremote.h"
#include "IRremoteInt.h"

VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinIR){

    _pinInput = pinIR;

    IRrecv receptorIR(_pinInput);         
    decode_results buffer;    

    _receptorIR = receptorIR;   
    _buffer = buffer;

}
```

Note: IRrecv and decode_results are custom types and their libraries are already included.

Comment: You need to show us the declaration of IRrecv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you **did not provide a whole code example**, I'll instead explain what's wrong since I can still tell.

Your constructor's definition is written like this:

```
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinIR)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Regardless of what `// stuff` is, the compiler will actually insert code...

```
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinIR)
// <--- here
{
    // stuff
}
```

Which calls the default-constructor of every non-POD-type instance in your class, in order, which you did not specifically initialize, in that same spot.

Because you didn't initialize `_receptorIR`, it is inserting a default-constructor call so your constructor REALLY looks like this:

```
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinIR)
:   _receptorID () // ERROR: No default initializer!
,   _buffer () // assuming _buffer is non-POD
{
    // stuff
}
```

However, `_receptorID` apparently does not have a default constructor that's accessible.

You SHOULD be doing this:

```
VS1838B::VS1838B(int pinIR)
:   _pinInput ( pinIR )
,   _receptorID ( pinIR )
,   _buffer ()
{
    // stuff
    // Note: you actually don't need to put ANYTHING you
    // wrote in your example here because the initializer-list
    // above did it all for you.
}
```

But seriously, **POST THE WHOLE CODE**. The error was CLEARLY with the constructor of IRrecv and you didn't even post its prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
IRrecv receptorIR(_pinInput);
```

`IRrecv` class don't provide one parameter constructor function，you should provide  it.